# How to get Google map api key from web config file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

How can i read google API Key from web config file and append it to google api reference.

I have jquery function in external file and i am adding reference to that file in asp.net page. I think it is not a good practice to add api key on page reference.

**aspx page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="../scripts/GeoCode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**external js file**

```
function GetGeoCode() {
var txtLat = $('[id$=txtLat]');
var txtLng = $('[id$=txtLng]');

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "my address";

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        txtLat.val(latitude);
        txtLng.val(longitude);

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I understand you may be worried about people "stealing" your key -

You will need it in your client side JS however, and no matter how hard you try to obfuscate it or hide it, it will be client side at some point, so someone that really wants to get hold of it, will.

The solution:
You can set allowed referrers, so that your key can't be used by others.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/auth#limiting_referrers